# How to call LsaLookupAuthenticationPackage from Rust

Tags: windows, winapi, rust, lsa

I'm trying to retrieve with Rust the unique identifier of the MSV authentication package. For that, i'm trying to use the Windows API function [LsaLookupAuthenticationPackage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ntsecapi/nf-ntsecapi-lsalookupauthenticationpackage), but it is returning the NTSTATUS constant 0xC00000FE (**STATUS_NO_SUCH_PACKAGE**), which acording to the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/596a1078-e883-4972-9bbc-49e60bebca55) it means "A specified authentication package is unknown".

To call LsaLookupAuthenticationPackage, I'm using [the official crate](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/Security/Authentication/Identity/fn.LsaLookupAuthenticationPackage.html) to access the Windows API. Below I detail the activities that I perform before calling LsaLookupAuthenticationPackage:

1.- I run my code as **System**.

2.- I successfully enable **SeTcbPrivilege** using the function **RtlAdjustPrivilege**.

3.- I successfully call **LsaRegisterLogonProcess** to open a handle to start the interaction with the LSA.

4.- I use this handle to call **LsaLookupAuthenticationPackage**. Below, I show the code that I'm using to call LsaLookupAuthenticationPackage:

```
let package:[char;20]= ['M','S','V','1','_','0','_','P','A','C','K','A','G','E','_','N','A','M','E','\0'];
let auth_package: STRING = STRING {Length:19, MaximumLength:19, Buffer:transmute(package.as_ptr())};
let auth_package_ptr: *const STRING = transmute(&auth_package);
let auth_id: *mut u32 = transmute(&u32::default());
let ret = LsaLookupAuthenticationPackage(handle,auth_package_ptr,auth_id);
```

I also tried to use an `&str` instead of the `char array` to store the auth package name, but it didn't work either.

For me it's obvious that the function is working, so the problem seems to be that I'm not passing correctly the auth package name.

Comment: `MSV1_0_PACKAGE_NAME` of course no such package. exist `MICROSOFT_AUTHENTICATION_PACKAGE_V1_0`

Comment: also not need have SeTcbPrivilege for query package number

Comment: @RbMm Yea, i just realized that MSV1_0_PACKAGE_NAME is the constant name, not its value ... Thank you!

Comment: Don't forget that a [`char`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html) in Rust is 4 bytes.

Comment: Also note that the `windows` crate provides the [`MSV1_0_PACKAGE_NAME`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/Security/Authentication/Identity/constant.MSV1_0_PACKAGE_NAME.html) constant definition, too.